# Third Omnidirectional Tracking Link is not staying on

Tags: eve-online

After the Rubicon patch went live, I noticed that the third Omnidirectional Tracking Link on my Armageddon refuses to run more than one cycle before deactivating.

The other two will cycle just fine, but not the third one. I've got plenty of cap and all three are loaded with the appropriate scripts.

Is this working as intended or is it a bug?

Comment: You don't even need a script, it should work weather you have one in there or not. It just gives different bonuses then. I call bug. Did you test any other random ship in your possession if it works there? Does not need to make sense, just for testing purposes to see if it is ship specific or not.

Comment: Don't have another ship right now, but one will be coming down soon, I can try it then.

Comment: You could also log onto the test server and see if the issue persists there and buy more ships for 100 ISK for testing. Of course you need to be able to fly them. But that would be less of a hassle if you sit in null sec, which I presume from what you said. And don't forget to report it to the dev team after you are done testing.

Comment: Ok so I tried it out on a Dominix (not on the test server), and all three stay on with no problem. It does look like a bug, so I filed a ticket with customer support. Lets see what they say.

Answer (score 2):

This is either a bug or you accidentally turned off module auto repeat.

Please check the following while undocked:

- right click your "working" modules and make sure you see an option "disable auto-repeat" available
- right click your "broken" module and see whether it gives you an "enable auto-repeat" or "disable auto-repeat" option

If auto-repeat is in fact turned on for that module, then you most likely encountered a bug.

Comment: Either way it would probably be a good idea to turn auto-repeat off and on again. Just to be sure the status is set properly (in case something screwed up).